# addMouseListener to the canvas in Rubber Banding

Tags: java, mouselistener, java-canvas

I'm trying to solve Rubber Banding problem of [Stanford CS106A](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111).  As per [Java Doc on addMouseListener()](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html#addMouseListeners%28%29) one needs a listener to use it. As per the solution to this problem no listener is used but when I use it without any listener I get the following error :

> The method addMouseListener(MouseListener) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments()

**How could a listener be created so that it listens to the canvas as a whole ?**

```
/**
 * This program allows users to create lines on the graphics canvas by clicking 
 * and dragging the mouse. The line is redrawn from the original point to the new
 * end point, which makes it look as if it is connected with a rubber band.
 */

package Section_3;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import acm.graphics.GLine;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class RubberBanding extends GraphicsProgram{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 406328537784842360L;

public static final int x = 20;
public static final int y = 30;
public static final int width = 100;
public static final int height = 100;
public static final Color color = Color.RED;
public void run(){
    addMouseListener();
}

/** Called on mouse press to create a new line */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    double x = e.getX();
    double y = e.getY();
    line = new GLine(x, y, x, y);
    add(line);
}
/** Called on mouse drag to reset the endpoint */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    double x = e.getX();
    double y = e.getY();
    line.setEndPoint(x, y);
}
/* Private instance variables */
private GLine line;

}
```

Comment: Check out [How to Write a Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: thanks. But i did checked it before posting the question. It shows that a how addMouseListener() could be used with a label. But I have to use it on the canvas. How is it possible to use addMouseListener() to track canvas and not a pre-specified label ?

Comment: so basically i want to add addMouseListener() to the canvas and not to any label.

Comment: Basically, you need implement a MouseListener

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to add a addMouseListeners() to the run() method and that was the issue. The above solution by me to add a GCanvas and listen to it works too but is not needed. The addMouseListeners() should have rather been initialised using init() and not within run(). I was not able to use init() before as I'm learning Java from  [Stanfrod CS106A](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111) which used a customised Karel.jar library reference. This library had made the init() method final so i was not able to refer to it in any program. After i removed the Karel.jar library and used the acm.jar from jtf i was able to use init() and also able to use the addMouseListeners() directly to the canvas without adding any other canvas on the already drawn canvas.
**So the whole problem was Karel.jar !**

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a GCanvas object and use addMouseListener() on that object.

```
        GCanvas c = getGCanvas();   //Creates a GCanvas component so that addMouseListener could be applied to it.
        c.addMouseListener(this);   //Tracks mouse event for the canvas
```

Then I was able to track mouse events for the canvas by implementing MouseInputListener as told by @madprogrammer .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RubberBanding extends GraphicsProgram implements MouseListener {
    public void run() {
        GCanvas c = getGCanvas();
        c.addMouseListener(this); 
    }

    @Override 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

}
```

You could either implement MouseListener at a class level like I did above.  You could also create a separate concrete class that implements it and pass and instance of that to the canvas instead of this.  You could even make a field variable equal to an anonymous class that implements the listener and pass it it Canvas object.

```
MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() {
    @Override 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
}

class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {
    @Override 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
}

public void run() {
    GCanvas c = getGCanvas();
    c.addMouseListener(listener); 

    // OR

    GCanvas c = getGCanvas();
    c.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener()); 

}
```